# Asking about self-destruct in solidity

Tags: solidity

[image]

i have the code in solidity, i'm wondering something: I deploy code for the 0x583... first, i send 1 eth to another account. Before i click withdrawAllMoney, i click destroySmartContract, 1 eth 's automatically send to receiver (this is okie!). But after that, i keep going send the 1 eth from 0x583.. to another account, it still take out eth from 0x583.. but the orther can't receive it.

I'm wondering: when i call the selfdistruct, is the contract real deleted (can't send or recieved...)

Thank you!

Comment: please, in your questions, any code should be inserted as text, by pasting and formatting it with the `{}` button. The usage of screenshots severely impair copy+paste for tweaking examples for your answer, readability, accessibility and the ability of both stackoverflow and google to index your code for future search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *when i call the selfdistruct, is the contract real deleted (can't send or recieved...)*

`selfdestruct()` effectively removes the deployed bytecode from the contract address.

In the next block, this (former contract) address will act as a regular address without a smart contract, so it is able to receive tokens and ETH.

But, since it doesn't hold any bytecode anymore, you won't be able to interact with the contract (it's not there anymore).